# How can I specify what dynamic input to submit in a table row on click with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, input, dynamic

My goal is to have a table with various items dynamically generated within a single form. Each row has a unique input value associated with the row. I would like the user to be able to click anywhere on the row (without a submit button) and have that input sent via  a POST request. I have only been successful in having the form submit the same input value for every item I select, as opposed to 1, 2, 3, etc. What am I missing?

```js
 $("tr").on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    var $form = $('#form1');
    
    $form.find("tr[id^='blah']").val(id);

    $form.submit();
    
  });
```

```html
<table>
<form method="POST" id="form1" action="action">
      <tr id="blah1" value="1">
         <input name="numberInput" value="1" type="hidden"/>
        <td><b>Item 1</b>
        <td><b>$5</b></td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr id="blah1" value="2">
         <input name="numberInput" value="2" type="hidden"/>
        <td><b>Item 2</b>
        <td><b>$8</b></td>
      </tr>
      
      ...
      
</form>
</table>
```

**Edit**

I figured it out myself. I added a unique identifier to the form, kept the form inside the table, and made the below modification to the jQuery.

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    var uniqueID = $(this).find("td:first-child > input").val();
    $("#formName" + uniqueID).submit();
});
```

Comment: Your `tr`s seem to be lacking parent `table`s, and they seem to have `input`s as direct children? That doesn't look valid...

Comment: Typo on my part. Are you implying for the latter that I should have multiple forms in conjunction with multiple inputs? Or that an input should be outside of each tr?

Comment: The only children of `tr`s should be `td`, I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I added a unique identifier to the form, kept the form inside the table, and made the below modification to the jQuery.

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    var uniqueID = $(this).find("td:first-child > input").val();
    $("#formName" + uniqueID).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, forms are not allowed inside tables but you can put entire tables inside forms.

Like this;

```
<form method="POST" id="form1" action="action">
  <table>
      <!--table content-->
  </table>      
</form>
```

Secondly, place your hidden input inside table data tags. So,

```
<tr id="blah1" value="1">
    <input name="numberInput" value="1" type="hidden"/>
    <td><b>Item 1</b>
    <td><b>$5</b></td>
</tr>
```

would be

```
<tr id="blah1" value="1">
     <td>
       <input name="numberInput" value="1" type="hidden"/>
     </td>
     <td><b>Item 1</b></td>
     <td><b>$5</b></td>
 </tr>
```

Thirdly, the way i'd approach this is to use pseudo selectors combine with a name selector. Here is what I mean;

https://jsfiddle.net/DejiO/sfdb53hy/13/

Comment: I've taken your comments and applied your jQuery, and can see the alert box indicating the value of each item that was clicked. However, the form submits every input in the form, as opposed to just the one that was selected.